# Unable to add firebase Crashlytics on flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

Unable to add Run script for auto-upload of dSYMs.

I am getting error

`/Users/anvarmk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hfhodpqynwvwnxemhvbplehhprlr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-7E6263EC2AEF6E0300D27552.sh: line 2: /Users/anvarmk/adil/innsof: No such file or directory /Users/anvarmk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hfhodpqynwvwnxemhvbplehhprlr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-7E6263EC2AEF6E0300D27552.sh: line 3: /Users/anvarmk/adil/innsof: No such file or directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?hl=en&authuser=0&platform=flutter)

added build script as mentioned in documentation
i am only facing this issue in ios

Comment: Did you removed derived data try it ?

Comment: yes i tried but i am getting same error